# How can I determine when a Bing map waypoint is going to overlap an existing one, and give the original waypoint a “badge-like” update?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-8

I want to be able to determine when a Bing map waypoint that I want to add is going to overlap an existing one, so that, rather than bunching them all up in one spot like a litter of kittens on a catnip plant, I can instead alter the text/"badge" of the existing waypoint marker so that it displays an indication that it has been "reached" N times.

For example, in showing where a person was, and marking the waypoint with a sequential number, I may want to update the text on the waypoint marker from "1" to "1,2" and then "1-3" or possibly just "1+" as there won't be enough room to display something like "1,7,42" etc.